# Count values in a range comprehended between two values

Tags: excel-formula

At Column A i have this values 1
0
3
2
0
5
1
1
1
0
2
1
1
1
0
2
1
1
1
0
0
3
0
2
0
0
3
1

This list grows everyday.
I need a formula to put on every cell of column B that counts upwards how many values bigger than 1 are until the next value = 1 is found.
In another words i need to count how many values larger than 1 are between 1's.
The pretended result would be something like this:

1
0
3
2
0
5
1   3
1
0
2
1   1
1
0
2
1   1
1
0
0
3
0
2
0
0
3
1   3

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper column, if this is acceptable.

So to create a running count of numbers greater than one which resets each time it encounters a '1', enter this starting in B2 and pull down (I'm assuming the data has a heading and the list starts with a 1) :-

```
=IF(A2=1,0,B1+(A2>1))
```

Then to display the counts at each '1' value (but not for repeated ones) enter this in C2 and pull down:-

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,A1<>1,ISNUMBER(A1)),B1,"")
```

[image]

It's also possible to do it with an array formula, but not sure if it's worth the effort:-

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,A1<>1),
   COUNTIF(
      OFFSET(
         A$1,
         MAX(ROW(A1:A$2)*(A1:A$2=1))-ROW(A$1)+1,,
         MAX(ROW(A1))-MAX(ROW(A1:A$2)*(A1:A$2=1))),
      ">"&0),
   "")
```

to be entered in B2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pulled down.